# Limiting the size of firebase realtime database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Is it possible to artificially limit the allowed size of the database. Let's say I want to limit the allowed size by 10MB and reject all other write requests.

Comment: There are no security rules that can be applied based on the size of the data.  You'll have to send all the writes through some other process that keeps track of the size.

Answer (score 0):

The size of the database will depend on how much data there is in the database, but the only way to limit it, is by using the security rules:

You can do this:

```
 {
"rules": {
  ".read": true,
  ".write": false
  }
}
```

The above will let anyone to read from the database, but no one can write to the database, thus nothing will be added and the size before having those rules(if u had `write:true`) will stay the same.

For example, if you have an application and you do not want anyone to write anything to the db after one month. Then you change to the rules above and the database will not be changed.

More info about rules here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/

Comment: I think that that is not what I exactly need. What I do need is to set up the threshold.

Comment: As you cannot control it other than this way. It is good, since you can stop anyone writing to the database after some time, and then you will stay on a fixed size

Comment: its better to limit no of  childs under the node..  { .validate": " 10000 = root.childs." .}; consider putting more validate on write.

Comment: yes the above was just a simple example, but OP does not want that anw